# I am trying to create a sql table in phpmyadmin, I'm getting 4 errors. This code works in phpmyadmin on my pc at my work but not on the pc at home

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
    employee_ID INT(11), PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    hourly_pay DECIMAL(10,2),
    position ENUM('Manager','Helper','Cashier','Cleaner') NOT NULL,
    employee_contact BIGINT(10) NOT NULL
    );
```

Here are the errors:

> A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "NOT NULL" at position 86)
>
> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 120)
>
> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "2" at position 123)
>
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "position" at position 132)

Comment: employee_ID INT(11) PRIMARY KEY - remove comma, voted to close because it's simple typo

Comment: Works in office but not at home! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove comma after `INT(11)`

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
    employee_ID INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    hourly_pay DECIMAL(10,2),
     position ENUM('Manager','Helper','Cashier','Cleaner') NOT NULL,
    employee_contact BIGINT(10) NOT NULL
    );
```